# document.body.style.backgroundColor is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript function that is called when the user clicks a div to get the current background color (white on my laptop) of the web page:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="checkbkcolor(id, 1)">Just testing the web page bk color
</div>
```

Here is the checkbkcolor() function:

```
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 // DOES NOTHING SO I COMMENTED IT OUT: document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

 function checkbkcolor(id, val)
 {
     // THIS RETURNS NOTHING FOR THE COLOR -- the alert box
     // only says "the document.body.style.backgroundColor is:  "
     // and nothing else
   alert("the document.body.style.backgroundColor is:  " 
                + document.body.style.backgroundColor);

   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

     // The alert box now shows 'red' for the color name, *AND* 
     // the web page's background has turned all red
   alert("the document.body.style.backgroundColor is:  " 
                     + document.body.style.backgroundColor);
 }
</script>
</head>
```

In other words:  my web page background is white when the page appears BUT the document.body.style.backgroundColor  is not set.

So is my web page set to 'transparent'?

I don't think so.  To test, I added the following CSS background color and when the web page *first* appears, the entire background is yellow:

```
  body
  {
     background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
  }
```

Now when my web page appears, it is no longer white (or transparent, whatever).
The web page is yellow when it appears.

AND STILL.  The following code shows the background color is not set:

```
 function checkbkcolor(id, region)
 {
     // THIS RETURNS NOTHING FOR THE COLOR
   alert("the document.body.style.backgroundColor is:  " 
                   + document.body.style.backgroundColor);

   // same code other as above
 }
```

My assumption is that my research (4 hours worth) on 'bgColor', 'background', 'backgroundColor' were not helpful.

Most of all I don't understand how the entire web page background can come up yellow when I set the 'body' in CSS to rgb(255,255,0) and yet the following alert box says the backgroundColor is NOT SET:

```
  alert("the document.body.style.backgroundColor is:  " 
              + document.body.style.backgroundColor);
```

I need to know, when the page first appears, what the background color is.
How?

EDIT:  I'm using the latest version of Firefox, version 22.0

Comment: Just a wild guess, maybe you need to assign the color after the page loading, using window.onload

Comment: any fiddle u hav created?

Comment: hi rgb(255,255,00 is yellow only...to get white its rgb(255,255,255)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You get an empty value in alert, because you haven't set the background color of the `body` before reading the value. In the second alert it gives you the value, since you've set it.

`document.body.style` represents *inline* styles in the `body`, not the style given in the stylesheet. If you need to get current values, you need to use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) like this:

```
bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

Note that you can access the style properties with CSS names using `getPropertyvalue()`, or JS style camelCase names:

```
var bodyStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null);
bgColor = bodyStyle.backgroundColor;
fgColor = bodyStyle.color;
...
```

Comment: Dang I was hopeful as the nuance of 'inline' vs. 'computedStyle' was unknown to me.  But I added that exact line of code and the alert box shows 'bgColor' is undefined.   `    var bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue('backgroundColor');    
    alert("the backgroundColor is:  " + bgColor);`

Comment: Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWyST/), with two different versions of the  `getComputedStyle()`. You get some unexpected results in the fiddle (due to the jsFiddle itself), but in your code it should be OK, definetely it should not return `undefined`. Please play with the fiddle, remove the style rule, change it, etc. Are you sure `document.body` exists at the time you execute this?

Comment: document.body I'm fairly certain must exist because the entire web page is up and visible, and only then can the user click on the div that invokes the javascript function to get the current page background color.

Comment: Well, `body` clearly exists : ). Only I can imagine, this would return `undefined`, if there's a typo in the argument of the `getPropertyValue()`. Please check the fiddle, and try that other version too.

Comment: I'm set, thanks Teemu -- here's the code that shows the color:  `var bgColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).backgroundColor; alert("the backgroundColor is, FINALLY:  " + bgColor);`    Just to let you all know -- if I set the 'body' style as in my CSS code above to yellow for the background, this code here correctly reports rgb(255,255,0).  AND ALSO -- if I remove the yellow bk color out of my 'body' in my CSS file, the alert box reports 'transparent' for the color.  THANKS Teemu.

Comment: I found that `window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).getPropertyValue("background-color")` or `window.getComputedStyle(document.body, null).backgroundColor` worked in Safari (note the css property name with the dash, not the camel case js property name when using getPropertyValue).

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because the `.style` can only access the inline `style` property. So if you assign `<body style="background-color: yellow;">` your script can work well.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the `style` property of HTMLElement instances references inline style definitions and those added via JS (`elem.style[prop] = value`). You can however access CSS properties in JS via the `document.defaultView.getComputedStyle`.

Comment: Actually styles set by `elem.style[prop] = value` are inline styles, you can see them in the HTML of a page.

Answer (score -1):

Change the css to

```
 #div1
  {
     background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
  }
```

and try