# Why can only certain CSS styles be accessed from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Here's an example block of css:

```
p {
  position: relative;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 100%; 
  top: 100px
}
```

Then if I include a paragraph tag which calls a javascript function upon being clicked:

```
<p onclick="logStyles(this)">Test</p>
```

Strangely, only some styles are accessible...

```
function logStyles(obj) {
    console.log(obj.style.color);
    console.log(obj.style.position);
    console.log(obj.style.fontSize);
};
```

The element's color value shows up in the console and I am able to change it's value to say "blue" from my javascript. But the second two functions log nothing to the console and those style values are inaccessible.

```
 red page.html:16
     page.html:17
     page.html:18
```

Why is this the case? I am running the latest version of Chrome.

The css and javascript files are included through links in the head as so:

```
 <script src="js_methods.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Comment: The "style" object on a DOM node only gives the styles that are directly associated with the element, not styles from CSS files.

Comment: A dup of [document.body.style.backgroundColor is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17588801/1169519)? Just for example, there's probably better posts available.

Comment: @Teemu I agree it's a dupe but can't quite remember the appropriate terminology to search for.

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about the COMPUTED style. That's something different from the inline style.

See: [How do I get a computed style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910004/how-do-i-get-a-computed-style)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was able to able to access fontSize for example by writing window.getComputedStyle(obj).fontSize

Answer (score 0):

By doing it this way you can only get the styles directly associated with the HTMLElement object. What you're looking for are the computed styles:

```
var styles = window.getComputedStyles(elem);
console.log(styles["color"]);
```

See [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)