# How get an elements background using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any take away for accessing element's css properties which are set by the class name for an element.

For the first div element, i have attached a red class by which i have set red as its background and when i try to access div's backgroundcolor in javascript i cannot. What is the right approach to access element's backgroundColor using javascript when set by css class

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.red');
  console.log(div.style.backgroundColor);
  var div_2 = document.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)');
console.log(div_2.style.backgroundColor);
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Element1
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Element2
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588801/document-body-style-backgroundcolor-is-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements do not have `background-color` set at the elements' `style` attribute. Use `window.getComputedStyle()` to get the element computed style set at `.css` file.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.querySelector('.red');
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor);
  var div_2 = document.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)');
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(div_2).backgroundColor);
}
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
  Element1
</div>
<div id="div1">
  Element2
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution