# javascript button.style.backgroundColor returns "" until clicked

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function chgBkColor(v) {
  v.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ?
    v.style.backgroundColor = "#50AAD7" :
    v.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
};
```

```css
.dowBtn {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.7em;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='chgBkColor(this);' id="su" class="dowBtn">Su</button>
```

When I click the button, the first click doesn't work and v.style is blank. I've tried various approaches to this using  documentGetElementById and all happen the same way.

Every click after works fine toggling the background color.

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: Try using computed style.....
Use
`var bgcolor = window.getComputedStyle(v, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
`

Comment: @Teemu Change the background color

Comment: @VíñịtVịłłă - Although I want to get the backgroundColor, I also want to change it. Can you add that?

Comment: Notice, that inline `style` is not the same as CSS stylesheet, stylesheet doesn't initialize inline style objects.

Comment: @mercator - I looked at the link you provided but the problem I'm having is setting the initial background. I also tried checking if the background color was already changed to #50AAD7 and it still won't set it on the first click.

Comment: It is set, but to the same color as you've set in the stylesheet, the problem root in the linked dup is the same.

Comment: [A backgroundColor issued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588801/document-body-style-backgroundcolor-is-undefined/17589043#17589043) dup, if you need an explanation closer to your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because you didn't initialize a color, so it doesn't equal anything and so it applies the white color:

```
<button onclick='chgBkColor(this);' id="su" class="dowBtn" style="background-color: #fff">Su</button>
```

When using `.style.xxx` you are accessing styles set directly on the element within the attribute `style="xxx"`, this doesn't include styles that are attached from within the `style` or `link` tags.

You would otherwise use [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method returns an object containing the values of all CSS properties of an element, after applying active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain. Individual CSS property values are accessed through APIs provided by the object, or by indexing with CSS property names.

This takes into account values set within a css class, and not just values set on the element basically you are accessing it's current visual style.

```js
function chgBkColor(v) {
    getComputedStyle(v).backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ?
            v.style.backgroundColor = "#50AAD7" :
                    v.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
};
```

```css
.dowBtn {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0.7em;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='chgBkColor(this);' id="su" class="dowBtn">Btn 1</button>
```

Comment: I updated with the style. Does that change anything?

Comment: What you are doing is defaulting the button to white, then getting a style that doesn't exist `.style.xxx` are styles applied directly to the element, not on a class. This is the reason it is doing this.

Comment: @JohnSmith I have made changes, take a look

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the value of your buttons background is undefined re-order your code and set a background like so:

```
<button onclick='chgBkColor(this);' id="su" class="dowBtn">su</button>
<script>
document.getElementById("su").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
function chgBkColor(v) {
v.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 255)" ?
        v.style.backgroundColor = "#50AAD7" :
                v.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
};
</script>
```