# Element is not hiding when I use style.display in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The function doesn't work, and does not hide the paragraph element. How to fix this?

```
  <html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           <p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
           <button class="buttonChange" onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
           <script>
                function changeText(){
                     let text=document.getElementById('paragraph');
                     if (text.style.display == 'block'){
                         text.style.display = 'none';
                     }
                     if (text.style.display == 'none'){
                         text.style.display = 'block';
                     }
                }
           </script>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: it is, but you're setting it back to `block` right after in your 2nd if.

Comment: You haven't defined the style for the element, it's style.display is not defined. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588801/document-body-style-backgroundcolor-is-undefined/17589043#17589043 , notice also what Stavm has said.

Comment: Use `else if` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <html>
    
    <head>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
      <button onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
      <script>
        const text = document.getElementById('paragraph');
    
        function changeText() {
          if (text.style.display == 'block') {
            text.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            text.style.display = 'block';
          }
        }
      </script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Use if else to choose one condition only

Answer (score 3):

At Page Load the Display style is empty also you are immediately checking again with an if statement, use **else if** or simply **else** if there is nothing else to check

```js
 function changeText(){
   let text=document.querySelector('#paragraph');
   if (text.style.display === 'block' || text.style.display === ""){
     text.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else if (text.style.display == 'none'){
     text.style.display = 'block';
   }
 }
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
<button class="buttonChange" onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code. your code has 2 issues

1st - You need to check for text.style.display == ''.
2nd - The 2 if block make it always visible as 1st if will hide then 2nd if will check if hidden then it will show. Use else instead of 2nf if.

```
<html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           <p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
           <button class="buttonChange" onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
           <script>
                function changeText(){
                     let text=document.getElementById('paragraph');
                     if (text.style.display == 'block' || text.style.display == ''){
                         text.style.display = 'none';
                     }else{
                         text.style.display = 'block';
                     }
                }
           </script>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

because you havent set the `display` of the `p` element

if you `console.log` the style of the `p` element, the `display` of the element is not `block`, it is blank `""`

```html
<p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
           <button class="buttonChange" onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
           <script>
                function changeText(){
                     let text = document.getElementById('paragraph');
                  console.log(text.style);
 
                }
           </script>
```

so you have to change it to `if (text.style.display === '')`

```html
<html>
       <head>
       </head>
       <body>
           <p id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
           <button class="buttonChange" onclick="changeText()">Change Text</button>
           <script>
                function changeText(){
                     let text = document.getElementById('paragraph');
                     if (text.style.display === '' || text.style.display === "block"){
                         text.style.display = 'none';
                     }else if (text.style.display === 'none'){
                         text.style.display = 'block';
                     }
                }
           </script>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the previous answers your code has 2 issues as mentioned.

Rather than using `|| text.style.display == ""` condition as suggested, you can always create your paragraph tag with style like below.

```
<p style="display:block" id="paragraph">Toggle Text</p>
```

You can choose the solution as you wish either with the OR condition or with the style attribute in P tag.